# using sys.columns from a different databases and servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Solution specified [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151359/pull-data-from-sys-columns-in-a-different-database),  works as follows (I run from `server1`)

```
select * from server1.blahdbname.sys.columns c 
where c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('blahdbname.dbo.blahtablename')
```

It is fine. Works as intended. But below query doesn't work (changed servername) (returns empty set)

```
select * from server2.blahdbname.sys.columns c 
where c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('blahdbname.dbo.blahtablename')
```

What is the universal way if I want to query different servers too? Above queries generated dynamically, so I want them to work on any server and db

**NOTE**: `blahdbname` and `blahtablename` both exist in `server1` and `server2`. `server1` and `server2` are linked

Comment: Do you have linked servers created for all the servers you want to query?

Comment: @TabAlleman , sure. Servers are linked, above query returns empty set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the function OBJECT_ID. This runs against the current database, not the remote database.

Instead you should use the system views on the remote server to make this happen.

```
select c.* 
from server1.blahdbname.sys.columns c 
join server1.blahdbname.sys.tables t on c.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'blahtablename'
```